# How to Create New Data Frames Whose Names Are Based On Each Iteration Of A For Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 10 Excel files that I want to read into R, with the following names:

- Data - January 2021.xlsx
- Data - February 2021.xlsx
- Data - March 2021.xlsx
- Data - April 2021.xlsx
- Data - May 2021.xlsx
- Data - June 2021.xlsx
- Data - July 2021.xlsx
- Data - August 2021.xlsx
- Data - September 2021.xlsx
- Data - October 2021.xlsx

I am able to write R code to do so 10 times, once for each month, as follows:

```
data_January_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - January 2021.xlsx")
data_February_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - February 2021.xlsx")
data_March_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - March 2021.xlsx")
data_April_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - April 2021.xlsx")
data_May_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - May 2021.xlsx")
data_June_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - June 2021.xlsx")
data_July_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - July 2021.xlsx")
data_August_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - August 2021.xlsx")
data_September_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - September 2021.xlsx")
data_October_2021 <- read.xlsx("Data - October 2021.xlsx")
```

However, since the file names differ only by month, I decided to write a for loop to streamline to process, as follows.

```
months <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October")

for (i in 1:length(months)) {
   data_[i]_2021 <- read.xlsx(paste0("Data - ", months[i], " 2021.xlsx"))
}
```

Again, the goal of this for loop is to create the following data frames in the R environment:

```
data_January_2021
data_February_2021
data_March_2021
data_April_2021
data_May_2021
data_June_2021
data_July_2021
data_August_2021
data_September_2021
data_October_2021
```

When I run this, however, I get the following error:

```
Error: object 'data_' not found
```

How would I fix the for loop to do just that?

Comment: You have not created the object `data` before you started to assign something to it. Don't use `data` as the name of an object because it is the name of a function. R will usually get it right, but when things are ambiguous (using an object name that does not exist), the error message may not be as clear as it would otherwise.

Comment: `data_[i]_2021` makes no sense. Square brackets are used for indexing. Here you are trying to use them to name an object based on the contents of `i`. If you are sure that you need to create these data frames with these names, you can use the `assign()` function (base package) with a call to `paste0()` for the x argument. You might also consider putting everything together in a single data frame or list instead.

Comment: @dcarlson I was using `data` as a hypothetical. So before the first statement in the for loop, something like `data_[i]_2021` <- data.frame()` would work?

@sashahafner Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and `list.files` to create a list of dataframes.

```
lapply(list.files(pattern="Data.*2021\\.xlsx"), \(x) readxl::read_xlsx(x))
```